# The "where" condition worked not as expected ("or" issue)

Tags: sql

I have a problem to join thoses 4 tables

[Model of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yldhx.png)

I want to count the number of reservations with different sorts (user [mrbs_users.id], room [mrbs_room.room_id], area [mrbs_area.area_id]).

Howewer when I execute this query (for the user (id=1) )

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM mrbs_users JOIN mrbs_entry ON mrbs_users.name=mrbs_entry.create_by 
                JOIN mrbs_room ON mrbs_entry.room_id = mrbs_room.id 
                JOIN mrbs_area ON mrbs_room.area_id = mrbs_area.id
WHERE mrbs_entry.start_time BETWEEN "145811700" and "1463985000" 
      or 
      mrbs_entry.end_time BETWEEN "1458120600" and "1463992200" and mrbs_users.id = 1
```

The result is the total number of reservations of every user, not just the user who has the `id = 1`.

So if anyone could help me.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses in the `where` clause whenever you have more than one condition.  Your `where` is parsed as:

```
WHERE (mrbs_entry.start_time BETWEEN "145811700" and "1463985000" ) or
      (mrbs_entry.end_time BETWEEN "1458120600" and "1463992200" and
       mrbs_users.id = 1
      )
```

Presumably, you intend:

```
WHERE (mrbs_entry.start_time BETWEEN 145811700 and 1463985000  or
       mrbs_entry.end_time BETWEEN 1458120600 and 1463992200
      ) and
      mrbs_users.id = 1
```

Also, I removed the quotes around the string constants.  It is bad practice to mix data types, and in some databases, the conversion between types can make the query less efficient.

Comment: Thank you. But when i use your first WHERE (....) the result is 23 and for the second WHERE(...) the result is 17. I don't understand why i have differents results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've faced caused by the incorrect condition `WHERE`.
So, should be:

```
  WHERE (mrbs_entry.start_time BETWEEN 145811700 AND 1463985000 )
         OR
        (mrbs_entry.end_time BETWEEN 1458120600 AND 1463992200 AND mrbs_users.id = 1)
```

Moreover, when you use only `INNER JOIN` (`JOIN`) then it be better to avoid `WHERE` clause, because the `ON` clause is executed before the `WHERE` clause, so criteria there would perform faster. 
Your query in this case should be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM mrbs_users 
     JOIN mrbs_entry ON mrbs_users.name=mrbs_entry.create_by 
     JOIN mrbs_room ON mrbs_entry.room_id = mrbs_room.id 
          AND
          (mrbs_entry.start_time BETWEEN 145811700 AND 1463985000 
            OR ( mrbs_entry.end_time BETWEEN 1458120600 AND 1463992200 AND mrbs_users.id = 1)       
          )         
     JOIN mrbs_area ON mrbs_room.area_id = mrbs_area.id
```

Comment: Ok but the result that i have is "#1305 - FUNCTION mrbs_room.id does not exist " I don't understand this error

Comment: Oh, I've forgot to add `and` after firts `join` criteria, see updated post

Comment: Oh yes thank i dont have error anymore but when i change the user, the result is always the same. Do you know where the problem may be is?

Comment: @VincentDUPONT this is not a problem, this is means that the second condition is not achieved. To verify that just remove the first condition and you will see is any records satisfied the conditions `mrbs_entry.end_time BETWEEN 1458120600 AND 1463992200 AND mrbs_users.id = 1`